# How can I update my json field in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following table myTable :

```
id info
1  {'email': 'bob@bob.com', 'country': 'USA'}
2  {'email': 'test@test.com', 'country': 'DE'}
```

I would like to update the field country like this :

```
id info
1  {'email': 'bob@bob.com', 'country': 'country1'}
2  {'email': 'test@test.com', 'country': 'country2'}
```

I tried this :

```
UPDATE myTable set info->country : format('country%s', id);
```

but it does not work

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||`:

```
update mytable set info = info || jsonb_build_object('country', info ->> 'country' || id::text)
```

Or using `jsonb_set()`:

```
update mytable set info =  jsonb_set(info, '{country}', to_jsonb(info ->> 'country' || id::text))
```

Comment: is building a new object faster than running `jsonb_set`?

Comment: @JonathanJacobson: I added the `jsonb_set()` solution to my answer. You might want to assess the performance of both options against your actual dataset.

Answer (score -1):

There's a [whole chapter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html) about that in the official documentation. You'll probably be interested in the `json_set` or `jsonb_set` functions.